Securely accessing MariaDB database from jar
I've built a simple game in Java with LibGDX that uses JDBC to connect to a MariaDB database and store various data from the game to the database. I want to eventually have the game connect to a cloud MariaDB database and a website on which I want to post my games that also connects to the database. The game is supposed to be deployed as a jar file. The problem is that I don't want a malicious user to decompile the jar and find out how to connect to the database and ruin things.
I did some research online and found out about java obfuscators, but I think a hacker may still be able to find the JDBC connection string in the code. I also, thought about creating a user with limited permissions to access the database from the code. But the user still needs to be able to update and read from one of the tables in the database, which a hacker can use to their advantage. I also saw online about using a web service instead of directly accessing the database from the code, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that from a desktop application. What do you think I should do? Any help is greatly appreciated.

You'll NEVER allow your client to directly connect to the db. You always wanna have a backend layer inbteween, which then connects to the db. This way your deployed game client has to authenticate against your game server (which you control), which then in turn will access the db on demand.

NEVER EVER! Check out Battle.net or Steam: they ask the user for their credentials; the application may remember the user's credentials for some time - which means it stores those credentials locally, but never-ever a global password. There is no way to make this safe.

Make the user enter their username and password. Ultimately it's only server-side db access that's secure though. If you want to use the same username and password for everyone then securing it is not possible

I'm not having a global username or password for everyone. Users are supposed to be assigned a code that they enter in the game to identify themselves. How do I implement a backend layer in between? That seems like a good idea, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

Well that would require a client server architecture. Of course this is normally a web app accessing a web server via the client browser

Is it possible to do this with my desktop application rather than a web app? Like have the jar connect to a server that connects to the database?

It does't matter what kind of client you use, whether it may be a mobile app, a web app, a standard website or as in your case a desktop application, it's always the same way: the client connects to the server, the server connects to the db. The architecture in question here is called Three Tier Architecture: https://www.ibm.com/topics/three-tier-architecture

Thanks, so how about I have the website (using Python Flask) connect to the db and send data via socket programming to the jar? Would that work?

Why would you "send data via socket programming" as opposed to doing jdbc?

Currently, I am using jdbc, but I thought that's not secure because the username and password is exposed in the code.

If you're using a 3 tier architecture as you say you plan to do, then the username and password problem goes away as they never appear in the client

So then how would jdbc connect to the server that connects to the database? I thought that it wouldn't be possible since jdbc needs credentials.

jdbc would be running on the same box as the database - totally opaque from the client. The credentials are stored in the webapp, which is also invisible to the client, though of course used by it
